# Compass and SASS on complex project structure

Tags: css, angularjs, compass-sass, yeoman

I'm developing an Angular application and I'm using the following folder structure:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── images
│   │   │   ├── brands
│   │   │   ├── coletaSeletiva
│   │   │   ├── quiz
│   │   │   └── vidaEmLem
│   │   │       └── avatars
│   │   ├── sass
│   │   └── stylesheets
│   ├── scripts
│   │   └── controllers
│   └── views
│       └── coleta
└── test
    └── spec
        └── controllers
```

This is the yeoman angular generated project.

The generated css that come from SASS is pointing to files with the following path `'/app/assets/...'`, because config in at the project's root.

My server is starting from app folder, so I call my assets using just `/assets/...`

What should I do?

Should I place config.rb inside of app folder and change assets paths?

My config.rb looks like this:

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "app/assets/stylesheets"
sass_dir = "app/assets/sass"
images_dir = "app/assets/images"
javascripts_dir = "app/assets/javascripts"
relative_assets = true
```

Comment: So are you running into a specific problem with this? Or are you just looking for opinions?

Comment: Everytime I need to change my css file because the path of my images used by classes is wrong. I want to know the best way to make this work, because I think config.rb should be on my root folder, right? If I'm managing my app I should  call all commands from the app root folder

Answer (score 0):

You can minify your code with "grunt" or "grunt --force". Then i think there will be no issues.

If still you got the issue of images . Try to set the path like **../images/image.png [if image folder is in parent folder]** or **./images/image.png [if image folder is in the same folder]**.